# force radio buttons to show inline

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to style a form with radio buttons.

Unfortunately display:inline is not making the radio buttons on the form inline. Neither is moving display:inline into css.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">   
    <div style="display:inline">
      <%= f.label "status_open", "Open" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :status, 'Open' %> <br />
      <%= f.label "status_active",  "Active" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :status, 'Active' %> <br />
      <%= f.label "status_closed",  "Closed" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :status, 'Closed' %> <br />
      <%= f.label "status_matched", "Matched" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :status, 'Matched' %> <br />   
    </div>      
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Source:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span6 offset3">
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/books" class="new_book" id="new_book"   method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"></div>

  <label for="book_title">Title</label>
  <input id="book_title" name="book[title]" size="30" type="text" />

  <label for="book_isbn">Isbn</label>
  <input id="book_isbn" name="book[isbn]" size="30" type="text" />

  <label for="book_edition">Edition</label>
  <input id="book_edition" name="book[edition]" size="30" type="text" />

  <label for="book_year">Year</label>
  <input id="book_year" name="book[year]" size="30" type="text" />

  <div style="display:inline">
  <label for="book_book_category_fiction">Fiction</label>
  <input id="book_category_fiction" name="book[category]" type="radio" value="Fiction" />
  <label for="book_book_category_non_fiction">Non-fiction</label>
  <input id="book_category_non-fiction" name="book[category]" type="radio" value="Non-fiction" />
  </div>
  <br />
  <input class="btn btn-large btn-custom-black" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Book" />
</form>  
</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas on why the buttons are not displaying inline? Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you'd like form elements to display inline with each other, you'll want to use the `form-inline` class.

In your source, change: `<div style="display:inline">`

to: `<div class="form-inline">`

That should get you headed in the right direction. There are many additional updates you could make to bring the whole form more inline with the guides layout by the Bootstrap team.

Here is an updated example:
http://jsfiddle.net/dusthaines/GTUK9/

As an aside, it's generally best practice for the radio button to be on the left, and its corresponding label on the right - my example reflects this small update as well.

Additional details @ http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

Comment: Thanks so much for your input! You suggestions solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, you might want to remove those `<br/>` tags between your radio buttons...

Comment: I suspected that as well but tool them off with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

`display: inline` should be applied to the items themselves, not the container. Please link the generated markup (HTML) for more help.

Comment: Can you explain your suggestion a little more, I should wrap each element with its own div styled with inline?

Comment: no, add CSS that refers to the element that gets created on the page `<head>` or in your external stylesheet.

Comment: I still don't follow. Do you mean <row>? Where is <head>?